# Loading animation not showing in ajax post request

Tags: jquery, ajax, post

for some reason my loading gif is not showing when I make my ajax post:

```
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
data: $(form).serialize(),
url: 'filetopost.php',
beforeSend: function() { $('#loading').show(); },
success: function(data) { 
$('#results').html(data);
 },
complete: function(data) {
$('#loading').hide();

    }
    });
```

No errors are showing in my chrome console either. Commenting out  `$('#loading').hide();` displays the results from the post and the loading gif image, but with it there, nothing happens. I know its correctly making a post though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be the server is responding so fast that before you see the loading image it gets hidden in the `complete` event. That is the reason if you comment out `$('#loading').hide()` you see the loading image.

Comment: I also didn't mention that the data from the post back isn't displayed when it is uncommented. Shouldn't the data be displayed on the website regardless of whether the loading gif is displayed or not? It makes sense what you wrote since I'm on local host.

Comment: Can you check in firebug what happens when you show the loading image?

Comment: What do you need me to check. When I run the code on firefox, it shows the correct post variable as well as 1 (correct value) in the html tab in html. It seems to be working fine, but isnt rendering the value on the page

Comment: Thanks for the help, it was a problem with my html.